# throw KeyUp event in MouseHover event in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events

I am trying to capture a KeyUp event when the mouse is over the map. I am using GMaps library.

I have tried using the keypress, keydown and keyup events of my gmap control (where the map is placed), and I have tried to use the keypress, keydown and keyup from the form events, but nothing happens.

In my form, I have also some buttons, and what I see when I press one of the rows keys is that the focus is changing among the buttons, The effect is as if you wanted to select a button using the arrows on the keyboard, and I don't know why is doing that, if I have a specific code in the key events of the program.

In the MouveHover event I am using this code:

```
Private Sub GMapControl_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GMapControl.MouseHover
    If Keys.Up <> Keys.None Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat + 1, GMapControl.Position.Lng)
    End If
End Sub
```

But I have not the behavior I am looking for. Also I am trying to use the KeyUp event of the form:

```
Private Sub BMS_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode.ToString = "Up" Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat + 1, GMapControl.Position.Lng)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.ToString = "Down" Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat - 1, GMapControl.Position.Lng)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.ToString = "Left" Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat, GMapControl.Position.Lng - 1)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.ToString = "Right" Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat, GMapControl.Position.Lng + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Also I have tried the same in the KeyUp event of the GMap control:

```
Private Sub GMapControl_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles GMapControl.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode.ToString = "Up" Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat + 1, GMapControl.Position.Lng)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.ToString = "Down" Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat - 1, GMapControl.Position.Lng)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.ToString = "Left" Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat, GMapControl.Position.Lng - 1)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.ToString = "Right" Then
        GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat, GMapControl.Position.Lng + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

And nothing...

Maybe someone has some ideas to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have continued finding an answer and I have found the response of what I was looking for on this thread
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ffeeea42-f6ba-420f-827e-74879fd29b26/how-to-detect-arrow-keys-in-vbnet?forum=winforms

By using the property:

```
Me.KeyPreview = True
```

In the Load method of the form, and using this code in the KeyUp of the form:

```
Private Sub BMS_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Right
            GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat, GMapControl.Position.Lng + 0.1)
            e.Handled = True
        Case Keys.Left
            GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat, GMapControl.Position.Lng - 0.1)
            e.Handled = True
        Case Keys.Up
            GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat + 0.1, GMapControl.Position.Lng)
            e.Handled = True
        Case Keys.Down
            GMapControl.Position = New PointLatLng(GMapControl.Position.Lat - 0.1, GMapControl.Position.Lng)
            e.Handled = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Anyway I would like to ask one thing I don't understand. I have tried this before but without using the **Me.KeyPreview** property, and without using the **e.Handled = true** property.

Could someone explain to me why using this two lines I have the behavior I want, and why without using them I was not able to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: KeyUp events are normally only raised on the control that currently has the focus. By setting `KeyPreview = True`, the form gets the keystroke first.

Comment: Thanks @SSS ! And what effect have the e.Handled = true in this case?

Comment: `e.Handled=True` stops the control with focus also handling the `KeyUp` event. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Control.KeyUp);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true

Comment: Thanks @SSS! You help me a lot with this